# Which layer/component should generate an UUID?

Tags: sql, oracle, nosql, distributed-computing, uuid

Considering a

- distributed, decentralized, REST API for a single page application,
- used world-wide,
- in which the entity ids are UUIDs,

which application layer should be responsible for the UUID generation for an entity insertion?

A few options: REST client application? REST implementation? Data base?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your code and platform. If your database supports generating ID you should prefer that. In case you have to generate it in your API implementation, prefer generating it in model of your framework.